# Xcode 4 tutorial for nav bar, tab bar, table view

Tags: iphone, xcode4, navigation, tableview, tabbar

I'm trying to find a good XCode 4 tutorial out there that does the following:

- Tab Bar Navigation
- Navigation Bar at top
- Table View for at least one Tab

I've started using this utube video from Xcode 3 but with very little luck.
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LBnPfAtswgw

I get really lost when trying to link the components together because the screens seemed to have changed dramatically from 3 to 4.

These 3 features are typically at the heart of most iphone applications, and finding it very hard to find a tutorial for Xcode 4 that accomplishes this.

Any advice would be great.  I've found some manual steps floating around but doesn't compare to watching a video of one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would really recommend the book [Beginning iPhone 4 Development Exploring the iOS SDK](http://www.apress.com/9781430230243). It contains everything you are looking for.